Bounding Box does not appear in Vertex Dataset
I'm trying to import my data into Vertex Dataset for my Object Detection use case, when I'm using Python API using method import_data from AI Platform, after process import done, there is no bounding box and label in my Vertex Dataset
Here is my script to use import
def import_vertex_dataset(dataset_id: str, bucket_path:str):
    
    bucket_path = f"gs://uri_bucket//{bucket_path}"
    print(bucket_path)
    
    aiplatform.init(project=project_id, location=region_id)
    
    dataset = aiplatform.ImageDataset(dataset_id)
    
    dataset = dataset.import_data(
        gcs_source=bucket_path, 
        import_schema_uri=aiplatform.schema.dataset.ioformat.image.bounding_box, 
        sync=True
    )
    
    print(f"Vertex Dataset Display Name : {dataset.display_name}")
    print(f"Resource Name: {dataset.resource_name}")

My dataset in bucket is in format .csv, and looked like this:
training, gs://bucket_uri/path_until_file_image, label, xmin, ymin, xmax, ymin, xmax, ymax, xmin, ymax

I think my format already the same with the documentation here, because while I'm using UI Vertex Dataset and choose option Select import files from Cloud Storage it works fine, and the bounding box appear with ML Use already decided

Hi , could you please share any screenshot which you'r facing in your console .
